# How do I correctly display a multilevel menu

Tags: php, yii2

how can I correctly display my multi-level menu.

There are two methods here, the first method builds a tree (recursion), the second method pulls all categories from the database. How to display the menu in the VIEW correctly and what it would be in `<option value = ""> Select the category </ option>`.

When I output and do a bust of the array, I lose a multilevel nesting, the third level does not appear and use a lot of foreach, too, as it is not clever?

This is the Category model

```
/**
 * Build tree
 * @param $data
 * @param int $parent_id
 * @return array
 */
protected function buildTree($data, $parent_id = 0)
{
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($data as $id => $node) {
        if ($node['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            unset($data[$id]);
            $node['childs'] = $this->buildTree($data, $node['id']);
            $tree[] = $node;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

/**
 * Get category
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllCategories()
{
    $data = self::find()->asArray()->all();
    $data = $this->buildTree($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Here is an example in a view.
The third nesting does not work or I do not know how to make an infinite nesting

```
<select id="category-parent_id" class="form-control" name="Category[parent_id]" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="">Select category</option>

        <?php foreach ($category->getAllCategories() as $cats) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $cats['id'] ?>"><?= $cats['title'] ?></option>

            <?php if ($cats['childs'] > 0) : ?>
                <?php foreach ($cats['childs'] as $cat) : ?>
                    <option value="<?= $cat['id'] ?>">--- <?= $cat['title'] ?></option>

                    <?php if ($cat['childs'] > 0) : ?>
                        <?php foreach ($cat['childs'] as $childs) : ?>
                            <option value="<?= $childs['id'] ?>">--- <?= $childs['title'] ?></option>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>


    </select>
```

Comment: check the https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ or change your question

Comment: I translate text!